# Windows 7 cannot find previously installed STM32 Virtual COM Port Driver

Tags: windows-7, usb, drivers, com

I have an STM32F4 Discovery board with a firmware that implements a USB CDC device. When connected I should see a virtual COM port device in the Window's Device Manager.

I have installed the [STM32 Virtual COM Port Driver](http://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stsw-stm32102.html) by running the **VCP_V1.4.0_Setup.exe**. My system is Windows 7, 32 bit.

The problem is when I connect the Discovery board the Windows says:

> No driver found.

The device name shows up correctly ("STM32 Virtual COM port") but Windows cannot find any driver either online or locally.

I have installed the driver, so I do not understand what is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that the driver installation was not complete. After running the **VCP_V1.4.0_Setup.exe** another exe should be executed to finish the installation of the driver.

The correct steps:

> 1- Uninstall previous versions (Start-> Settings-> Control Panel-> Add or remove programs)
>
> 2- Run your "VCP_V1.4.0_Setup.exe"
>
> 3- Go to Your installation directory - Example, C:\Program Files (x86)\STMicroelectronics\Software\Virtual comport driver
>
> 4- Go to Your OS version directory ([Win7] or [Win8])
>               + Then :
>                   - Double click on dpinst_x86.exe if you are running a 32-bits OS version
>                   - Double click on dpinst_amd64.exe if you are running a 64-bits OS version
>               + Follow the instructions.

These are included in the readme file, which is only attached if you download the driver from the official site.